# Transit visa to travel to Manchester airport via london

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I am from India going to Bangor, Wales for higher studies and my destination airport is Manchester via London Heathrow.

Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: As a comment, there are direct trains from Manchester to Bangor, but there are is also a direct London Underground connection from Heathrow to King's Cross, which is a ten-minute walk to London Euston, and there are also direct trains from Euston to Bangor. Your second flight may be unnecessary.

Comment: @TRiG And, in news that will be bizarre to people not familiar with the UK rail network, the direct train from Euston to Bangor (about 450km) and the trains from Manchester Airport to Bangor (only about 150km but involving a ~30min wait at Chester) both take about three hours. On the other hand, the asker might be planning to travel by bus, which would be quite a bit faster from Manchester than from London.

Answer (score 16):

"Transiting" means entering a country only for the reason of changing planes etc. to continue on towards your destination in a different country. For example, if you flew from India to Germany and then immediately from Germany to the UK, you would be transiting in Germany.

You are not transiting in the UK because, the UK (England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland) is one country. You are going to London only so that you can take another plane, but that second plane is not to a different country.

The visa that you need for your studies is the only visa you will need to enter the UK.

Comment: For an explanation of the differences between the countries contained within the UK, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNu8XDBSn10

Comment: Or a short version is that, as a matter of courtesy you may refer to Wales as a separate country from England. That is to say, don't go up to drunk Welsh people and scream "it's not a country, it's a principality", even if that's technically true. But from the POV of legal jurisdiction "England and Wales" is one unit (Scotland is another). From the POV of travel and immigration the UK is one unit.

Comment: @SteveJessop Saying "It's not a country, it's a principality" is like saying, "It's not a country, it's a democracy" or "It's not a fruit, it's an apple." A principality is a type of country. Neither England nor Wales is a sovereign nation and, although referring to either of them as "countries" is technically correct in some contexts, it really isn't helpful to somebody who's confused about whether they need a transit visa to change from an international flight to a domestic flight at Heathrow.

Comment: @David: It's not constitutionally a principality: the *only* sense in which it's a principality is that it has a titular prince. I don't see that having a titular prince necessarily makes a territory a country, but YMMV and in common parlance it is a country either way. Anyway the point is that declaring Wales "is not a country" may occasionally be seen as fighting talk, even though it's the correct assumption for visa matters.

Comment: That is, you've given the correct immigration advance (so far as I know), but let's not allow some innocent foreign student to put his foot in it on arrival in Bangor because he's learned on the internet that England and Wales are not "different countries" ;-)

Comment: Anyway, Manchester and London are *certainly* in the same country, by any definition.

Comment: @SteveJessop Honestly, that's just sematics: the UK uses the word "country" for things that are not countries in the conventional sense of the word. (Just as the USA uses the word "state" for things that are not nation states.) The key point here is not to let some innocent foreign student be under the impression that he needs a transit visa in London because his destination is in "another country" when it's actually just in another subnational entity.

Comment: Cue the well known (if apocryphal) practical jokes of making someone hide in the luggage space of a vehicle crossing the Severn Bridge, in order to avoid being caught and deported by customs and immigration checks at the border between England and Wales. (There are no such checks, of course).

Answer (score 7):

Bangor, Manchester and London are all in the same country (United Kingdom), so A visa that will allow you to get in to the UK should be useable for any method of entry, specifically it shouldn't matter if you enter in Heathrow or in Manchester.

I also believe you'll go through immigration in Heathrow, and the flight to Manchester is a domestic route.

Comment: You will go through immigration at Heathrow, but (IIRC) customs at Manchester. 
I haven't flown through Manchester, but if it's like Glasgow or Edinburgh then: as you are on an domestic flight, you will come through the domestic baggage collection. There will be a customs desk in the collection area, at which you should declare any items than need to be declared.